# Reverse bob jenkins hash function

Tags: hash, reverse

Does anyone know how I can reverse this function to produce the original input strings? 
As in the title this is a Bob jenkins hash function and all the inputs are either folder names or file names with extensions.

```
public static uint Hash(string str)
    {
        uint value = 0, temp;
        var index = 0;
        var quoted = false;

        if (str[index] == '"')
        {
            quoted = true;
            index++;
        }

        str = str.ToLower();

        for (; index < str.Length; index++)
        {
            var v = str[index];

            if (quoted && (v == '"')) break;

            if (v == '\\')
                v = '/';

            temp = v;
            temp = temp + value;
            value = temp << 10;
            temp += value;
            value = temp >> 6;
            value = value ^ temp;
        }

        temp = value << 3;
        temp = value + temp;
        var temp2 = temp >> 11;
        temp = temp2 ^ temp;
        temp2 = temp << 15;

        value = temp2 + temp;

        if (value < 2) value += 2;

        return value;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That function takes any string and only returns an unsigned `int` - it cannot possibly be generally reversible.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer, would there possibly be a way of using brute force instead to work out the original string from the returned int?

Comment: No. Hashes are one-way functions. If all you have is a hash, the best you could do by brute-force is finding all possible strings that map to that hash - and that set can be _infinite_.